# Black bar is seen when uitabbar hides Applozic SDK

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, chat, applozic

I have integrated Applozic inside `UITabViewController` and in `viewDidLoad` method written the following code to do this:

```
var controllers = self.viewControllers

    let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Applozic", bundle: Bundle(for: ALMessagesViewController.self))
    let controller = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ALViewController") as! ALMessagesViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    nav.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "icon_chat")
    nav.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 0, bottom: -12, right: 0)

    ALUserDefaultsHandler.setBackButtonHidden(true)

    controllers?.removeFirst()
    controllers?.insert(nav, at: 0)

    self.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
```

Here I am just creating instance of `ALViewController` and use it as a tab control. Everything is working fine as we can see here.

[image: Screenshot 1]

However, the issue comes when I tap any chat to Open chat window or try to create new chat, create group and every other screens where the tab bar is hidden. Whenever, tabbar is hidden black bar comes at bottom as we can see here.

[image: Screenshot 2]

I need to remove that black bar at bottom when the tab bar is hidden. Would anyone please help me getting rid of that black bar?

I have gone through some answers but have to change Applozic storyboards which I feel is not a proper solution as my pod updates I need to repeat these changes. However, when I open any chat from APNS black bar does not come. Black bar only comes when I go to any other screens from main chat window in tab bar. I have not managed anything manually.

Comment: no @chirag90 it was not working. I have used a 3rd party framework - Applozic and in their screens only such black bar comes. I my application its working fine. I tried such solution in XIB and storyboard on this framework also but they did not have any effect. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? im having real issues getting their views into a tabitem on my current nav.

Comment: I think it's better to ask their tech support for this problem.

Comment: @ZacPowell In case of Non-translucent tab bar, you can enable 'Hide bottom bar when pushed' setting of the parent VC(Container View controller).

Comment: @ZacPowell i have dedicated whole tab for Applozic and so in tabbar didselect i just hardcoded when Applozic tab is selected, make tabbar translucent and make opaque for other tabs. I am not listening any events from Applozic push or display actions does not matter.

Comment: Icontacted their TechSupport and followed their instructions to solve the issue